# timeoutMsgs no clue what is this in the Logs

Tags: converters, thingsboard

We are having for the third time the problem of not being able to visualize the data from our devices in our dashboard. The data is being transmitted to the "Data converter", but from there it does not arrive to "Device groups". This is not good for our project, as we need data without gaps. Our IT has identified the following "timeoutMsgs" and we have no clue what does it mean, and what to do to solve the issue. Please see below what he identified in the Logs:

```
2021-03-31 11:16:26,811 [TB-Scheduling-3] INFO o.t.s.s.queue.TbCoreConsumerStats - Core Stats: totalMsgs = [42] sessionEvents = [0] getAttr = [0] subToAttr = [0] subToRpc = [0] toDevRpc = [0] subInfo = [42] claimDevice = [0] deviceState = [0] subMsgs = [0] coreNfs = [0] scheduler = [0]
2021-03-31 11:16:26,902 [TB-Scheduling-8] INFO o.t.s.s.q.TbRuleEngineConsumerStats - [Main] Stats: totalMsgs = [53] successfulMsgs = [32] timeoutMsgs = [21] failedMsgs = [0] tmpTimeout = [0] tmpFailed = [0] successfulIterations = [13] failedIterations = [6]
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!